# unable to open FileInputStream

Tags: android, file, fileinputstream

I have a problem reading a file using `FileInputStream` object.
The file I would like to open, exists (I've created it with the same app and I can see it with a file manager on my device).
that's the method:

```
public String readFile(String name) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        String res = "", read;
        File tmp = new File(directory, name);
        fis = new FileInputStream(tmp);

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        read = buffered_reader.readLine();
        while (read != null) {
            res = res + read;
            Log.i("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "letto"+read);
            read = buffered_reader.readLine();
        }
        isr.close();
        fis.close();
        return res;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("AAAAAAAAAA", "Letto un cazzo");
    return null;
}
```

Where directory variable is declared as:

```
private static File directory;
```

That stores a static object file of application directory.
Where is the problem?

Logcat says that

> open failed enoent (no such file or directory)

on row

```
fis = new FileInputStream(tmp);
```

Comment: is your file name/location/extension ok?

Comment: sure, the same class use the same variables for function that write file

Comment: added necessary permission?

Comment: permission are ok, on manifest i've add

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE??

Comment: How can i add both permission on manifest? iv'è try like:

<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE | android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

but eclipse sign an error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26198/discussion-between-stinepike-and-giozh)

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> open failed enoent (no such file or directory)

My suggestion is to fix it as

```
FileInputStream fis;
File tmp = new File(directory, name);
if (tmp.exists() && tmp.isFile()) {
   fis = new FileInputStream(tmp);
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
   BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
   // next lines ...
}
else {
  // error
}
```

So there is not way how to make it work. You need to pass correct `FILE_PATH` or it won't work. Also check if you have permission for reading and writing.

Comment: on logcat appear that path is /storage/emulated/0/Appname/filename.
i don't know what is emulated/0/

Answer (score 0):

`FileInputStream openFileInput(String nameOfFile)`

Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for reading.

From the Api. I have used it and didn´t have a problem.